# Concatenate All Values of an Array

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

I have a loop like this below:

```
foreach ($header as $i) {
    $i += $i;
}
```

I am trying to load a variable ($i) and then outside of that loop echo that variable like this below:

```
echo $i;
```

However it always returns 0;

Is it possible to get it to return the value that it created in the loop?

Comment: if you are trying to concatenate strings from an array, check out the implode function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($header as $i) {
    $i += $i;
}
```

The above code has many problems.  Other answers solve them, but with bare explanations, so you might find this helpful. For the purposes of this answer, I will assume `$header` contains `array('a', 'b', 'c')`, and that your intention was to concatenate the values.

Firstly, you're using the numeric addition operator `+=` instead of the string concatenation operation `.=`. This is why `$i` is always 0: The values of `$header` are converted to integers each time you attempt to add with `+=`, assuming they don't start with numbers, they will always convert to the integer `0`.

Secondly, if you *were* concatenating with `.=`, you'd be assigning to `$i` each time through the loop, so its previous value would be destroyed. On the first pass of the loop, you're effectively doing this:

```
$i = 'a';
$i .= $i' // aa
```

On the second pass, you're doing this:

```
 $i = 'b';
 $i .= $i; // bb
```

And so on.  You need to use a different variable to store each element of the array and hold the concatenated values. Otherwise, when the loop exists, `$i` will *always* be the last value of the array, duplicated.

Finally, you should always declare your variables before attempting to *read* from them, which is implied by all the shorthand (`+=`,`.=`,`*=`,etc) operators. It's a very good idea to include `E_NOTICE` in `error_reporting` in php.ini so that you'll see the notice this raises.

Comment: Thanks alot dude, I got it, everyones help was very helpful

Answer (score 19):

You can use `implode()` to combine all the values.

```
$all = implode('', $header);
```

http://php.net/implode

Comment: +1 but you should explicitly pass an empty string as the first parameter, e.g., `implode('', $header);`

Comment: @webbiedave: Why?  It says in the manual that it defaults to an empty string.

Comment: @webbiedave `string implode ( array $pieces )` is indeed a completely valid use

Comment: I'm certainly not saying the usage is invalid (I upvoted the answer). The manual states: "glue: Defaults to an empty string. This is not the preferred usage of implode() as glue would be the second parameter and thus, the bad prototype would be used." This makes me believe that calling without the glue is the same as calling the prototype `implode(array $pieces, $glue = '');` which, according to the manual, is the more "confusing" prototype. They seem to recommend calling as `implode(string $glue, array $pieces);`. This certainly wouldn't be the first time that the manual itself was confusing.

Comment: @webbiedave: that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 6):

`$i` is re-assigned every time the loop iterates.

create a variable outside the loop, add to it during the loop, and echo again outside of it.

```
$outside_var = 0;

foreach ($header as $i) {
    $outside_var += $i;
}

echo $outside_var;
```

Comment: I was thinking that $i would be a string $i + $i, is this not the case?

Comment: If it's a string, you need to concatenate it by doing $outside_var .= $i; The + operator is only for integers

Comment: If you want to append to a string, then it should be `$outside_var .= $i;`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, my example is just that, an example, not sure what the data looks like, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: `$i` actually is not recreated each time the loop executes. The first time `$i` is assigned to, it exists in the loop's parent scope. It is however 'recreated' in that the next value of `$header` is assigned over-top of the previous value.